# Basic Facts of Division

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is rather embarrassing, but I haven't had much acquaintance with elementary facts of division. I am working on part $3$ of [link](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/decide-whether-or-not-a-given-subset-of-a-group-is-a-subgroup/).

Here are my questions:

Let $q,p,n\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $q\mid n$ and $p\mid n$. Denote $d=\operatorname{gcd}(q,p)$.  Then let $q=kd$ and $p=ld$.

1. Why is it that $kld = \operatorname{lcm}(q,p)$?
2. Why does $\operatorname{lcm}(q,p) \mid n$?  I can see how $\operatorname{gcd}(q,p)$ would divide $n$, but not $\operatorname{lcm}(q,p)$.

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, as a whole it is a lot, but you only need to read part 3.

Comment: $kld = \operatorname{lcm}(q,p)$ because that's basically how $\operatorname{lcm}$ is defined -- $$\operatorname{lcm}(q,p) = \frac{qp}{\operatorname{gcd}(q,p)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $a\mid b$ *means* there is some (positive, since we are dealing with positive integers, here) integer $c$ such that $b = ca$.

Note that $kld = (kd)l = ql$ and $kld = k(ld) = (ld)k = pk$.

Thus $kld$ is a multiple of both $p$ and $q$, i.e., a common multiple.

Now suppose $n$, let's say, is *any* common multiple of $p$ and $q$ (this is what we mean when we say $p\mid n$ and $q\mid n$), so let's say:

$n = pu = qv$.

Since $p = ld$, we have $n = ldu$, and similarly, $n = kdv$.

Clearly, $\dfrac{n}{kld} = \dfrac{ldu}{ldk} = \dfrac{u}{k}$.

Similarly, $\dfrac{n}{kld} = \dfrac{kdv}{kdl} = \dfrac{v}{l}$.

Thus $\dfrac{u}{k} = \dfrac{v}{l}$, or, put another way: $ul = vk$.

To finish, we need to prove an observation about $k$ and $l$, namely $\gcd(k,l) = 1$.

For suppose not, suppose $f\mid k$ and $f\mid l$, with $f > 1$. This means $k = fs$, and $f = lt$ for some (positive) integers $s,t$. Going back to $p$ and $q$ we have:

$p = ld = ftd = (df)t$, and $q = kd = fsd = (df)s$.

Thus $df$ is a common divisor of $p$ and $q$, but $df > d$ (since we assumed $f > 1$), and $d$ is the *greatest* common divisor, which is a contradiction.

So the only actual possibility for a common divisor of $k$ and $l$ is $1$. In particular this means that any prime occuring in the factorization of $k$ does *not* occur in $l$.

Now back to $ul = vk$. By equality, since clearly $k \mid vk$, we have $k \mid ul$. But none of the primes occuring in the factorization of $k$ occur in $l$, so they must all occur in $u$ (make sure you are clear on this). See if you can figure out why this means that $k \mid u$.

If $k \mid u$, that means $\dfrac{u}{k}$ is an *integer*, that is: $kld \mid n$.

(My apologies for all the extra leters)